# Для чего нужны дженерик параметры <T> если в конъюнктуре делегата все типы данных строго определены?

Tags: c#, делегаты, параметры

Такой вопрос, для чего в объявлении делегата в данном примере нужны дженерик параметры <Т1, Т2> если их нет в конъюнктуре метода на который  ссылается делегат, то есть все входные и выходные параметры определены конкретным типом данных, что определяют Т1 и Т2? (без них ошибка).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication14 
{ 
delegate bool askUser <T1, T2> (string question, Action<string> action, out int age); 

class Program 
{
static bool AskUser(string questionText, Action<string> tellUser, out int age)
{ // метод на который ссылается делегат askUser
return false; 
}
```

Comment: Во, так немножко получше, но всё-таки уделите немного времени на освоение Markdown и причешите текст.

Comment: Не стоит удалять вопросы, особенно если на них уже даны ответы. Кто-то потратил своё время и вы делаете труд этого человека бессмысленным.

Comment: @Nick я понял меня уже ткнули за это в повторном вопросе, очень извиняюсь, просто это мой первый вопрос на портале и я не знал. Впредь такого больше не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы не присвоили ничего `out`-параметру `age`.

С присвоением код [компилируется](http://ideone.com/WiJLxg) и без generic-параметров:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication14 
{ 
    delegate bool askUser(string question, Action<string> action, out int age); 

    class Program
    {
        static bool AskUser(string questionText, Action<string> tellUser, out int age)
        {
            age = 0;
            return false;
        }

        static public void Main()
        {
            askUser f = AskUser;
        }
    }
}
```